# Adjectives and nouns to describe an answer that doesn't answer the question?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard of the adjectives 'nonresponsive' or ['unresponsive'](http://thelawdictionary.org/unresponsive-answer/), but are they restricted to law^?

> Collins Dictionary: [nonresponsive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nonresponsive) =
>       not responsive, not reacting to a stimulus

The definition above differs from the definitions of adjectives like 'equivocate,  evade' and nouns like ['dodging'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/181510/50720), but these are negative and accusive; I prefer neutral connotation.

^Only if you wish, please see: http://law.indiana.edu/instruction/tanford/web/reference/objections.html, [p 169 of *The Trial Lawyer: What it Takes to Win*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zhEPN-B9VhkC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=unresponsive+witness&source=bl&ots=niRVtEgCAR&sig=6ohQN1MDUFUEDTkaEP2ATOGUUX0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_si1VPONEMqbyASk5IGoDA&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=unresponsive%20witness&f=false) by David Berg,
[p 271 of *Trials: Strategy, Skills, and the New Power of Persuasion*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jtTX1S0qU7MC&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=unresponsive+witness&source=bl&ots=ym7pOcsnSX&sig=-01XWXEOGjHlRt_rhBntz7MGBIA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_si1VPONEMqbyASk5IGoDA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=unresponsive%20witness&f=false)
by Thomas A. Mauet.

Answer (score 2):

How about calling it an **irrelevant** answer? [Merriam-Webster's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrelevant) of "irrelevant" is "not important or relating to what is being discussed right now."

You could also call the answer [**insufficient**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insufficient?show=0&t=1421203691), which Merriam-Webster defines as "not having or providing enough of what is needed." However, this seems to be more suited to a situation when someone answers part of the question but not all of it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Off-topic
2. Non sequitur
3. Inapplicable
4. Tangential
5. A politician, as in any answer a politician gives to any question